# In UNIX Terminal How to get a part of filename in a folder?

Tags: unix, filenames

I have a list of n files in a folder have some format.

Eg: ABCD.EXXXX.ZZZZ.ZZZZZ.txt

in above file ABCD.E is common for all the files,ZZZZ.ZZZZ is user wish string and i need to extract XXXX from all the files , need to display distinct XXXX to user.. Is there any way to do so.? Help me out in doing so.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Use ls -1 to make a list of the relevant files.  Pipe it into sed to strip the beginning 'ABCD.E'.  Then pipe it into sed again to remove everything after the first '.'

```
ls -1 ABCD\.E*\.txt | sed 's/^ABCD\.E//' | sed 's/\..*//'
```

Alternatively, if you want a little more control of the output you can do the second bit with awk

```
ls -1 ABCD\.E*\.txt | sed 's/^ABCD\.E//' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="."}{print "value =", $1, "user=", $2"."$3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"."'{print $2}' filename
```

You can try printing `$1`, `$2` ,`$3`... to get more understanding of command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bash/ksh parameter subsitution `#` and `%` for this from inside the shell.

```
function get_filename_section {
    typeset f=${1:?}
    typeset r=${f#ABCD.E}
    print ${r%.ZZZZ.ZZZZZ.txt}
}
```

Testing:

```
[[ $( get_filename_section ABCD.EXXXX.ZZZZ.ZZZZZ.txt ) == XXXX ]] &&
    echo ok || echo no
```